# Markdown matrix arrow labels

Tags: markdown

[image]

Anyone know how to add arrow labels to a matrix like above in markdown?

Comment: Where did you see this? I'm not aware of Markdown having any support for this. Are you sure it was not just an embedded image in the markdown?

Comment: What makes you think that [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) can do anything like this? Maybe you mean TeX / [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)?

Comment: some markdown processors (e.g. pandoc), allow raw TeX inside markdown...